# Dynamically build a 3d cylinder of elements with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

**UPDATE:** I've cleaned this up a lot (I think), but it also seems to be worse.  Here is a fiddle with some added features like using arrow keys to rotate the object. This makes it easier to see the problems.

https://jsfiddle.net/scottbeeson/ue4c7ocj/

---

**original question**

I'm trying to create a 3D vertical carousel dynamically using JQuery, based on the [tutorial and demo here](https://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/docs/carousel.html).  I'm trying to start out as basic and dynamic as possible, but it's not coming together (literally).

Here is what I have:

```js
function RotaMenu ( e ) {
 this.element = e;
 this.rotation = 0;
 this.panelCount = this.element.children().length;
 this.panelSize = $(this.element).outerHeight();
 this.theta = 360 / this.panelCount;
 this.radius = Math.round( ( this.panelSize / 2) / Math.tan( Math.PI / this.panelCount ) );
 console.log("Created new menu: panelCount=" + this.panelCount + ", panelSize=" + this.panelSize + ", theta=" + this.theta + ", radius=" + this.radius);
}

RotaMenu.prototype.update = function() {
 this.theta = 360 / this.panelCount;
 this.radius = Math.round( ( this.panelSize / 2) / Math.tan( Math.PI / this.panelCount ) );
 for ( i = 0; i < this.panelCount; i++ ) {
  panel = $(this.element).children()[i];
  angle = this.theta * i;
  $(panel).css('transform','rotateX(' + angle + 'deg) rotateY(0deg) translateZ(' + this.radius + 'px)');
 }
};


$(function() {
 var mainmenu = new RotaMenu($('#mainmenu'));
 mainmenu.update();
});
```

```css
.rmenu {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
.rmenu div {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mainmenu" class="rmenu">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
  </div>
```

Here is what it looks like with 6 children.  What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***updated***

So now I see on my computer why the version you had before needed the adjustment to radius that I had added earlier. This is because you were correctly calculating based on the height, and of course your goal was vertical. There's only two minor changes to effect this difference: `rotateX` instead of *Y* and use the correct radius calculation that you had before. Reflecting those changes I have edited the answer. I believe this will be what you are looking for.

#### solution

I think your main issue is that you are missing some css that makes it easier to get the basic structure up so you can debug it. You also need the outer container so you can add a camera point for the perspective so the transform looks pretty, otherwise it will look flat.

here's my sample: https://jsfiddle.net/8ymm7xu6/2/

important CSS:

```
.rmenu {
  position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
.rmenu div {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  perspective: 1000px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

and the html change

```
<section class="container">
  <div id="mainmenu" class="rmenu">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
  </div>  
</section>
```

there were also changes to the jquery:

```
function RotaMenu ( e ) {
    this.element = e;
    this.rotation = 0;
    this.panelCount = this.element.children().length;
    this.panelSize = $(this.element).children().first().outerHeight();
    this.theta = 360 / this.panelCount;
    this.radius = Math.round( ( this.panelSize / 2) / Math.tan( Math.PI / this.panelCount ) )
    console.log("Created new menu: panelCount=" + this.panelCount + ", panelSize=" + this.panelSize + ", theta=" + this.theta + ", radius=" + this.radius);
}

RotaMenu.prototype.update = function() {
    for ( i = 0; i < this.panelCount; i++ ) {
        panel = $(this.element).children()[i];
        angle = Math.round(this.theta * i);
        $(panel).css('transform','rotateX(' + angle + 'deg) translateZ(' + this.radius + 'px)');
    }
};


$(function() {
    var mainmenu = new RotaMenu($('#mainmenu'));
    mainmenu.update();
});
```

- panelSize needed to go off the panels, not the panels container
- <s>radius needed to increase by panelCount</s>
- no off-axis rotation (At least not yet!)

Comment: If I change rotateY back to rotateX to make it vertical (like my original post), it looks almost identical to my original screenshot.  https://jsfiddle.net/8ymm7xu6/1/

Comment: I updated the OP with a fiddle that has some improvements, but they layout it still all wrong, maybe worse.

Comment: I'm so sorry I misread your post - I thought that you were having trouble with a horizontal rewrite, not a vertical modification. I'm away from the pc now but will take a look later. A lot of the same changes will have to be made.. You were getting a panelSize of 0

Comment: Actually, looking at your fiddle, that looks right. Take another look... You probably want to modify the sizes/spacing . The main visual difference is that mine uses perspective in an outer container

Comment: This looks right?  https://i.imgur.com/t9UqBDY.png

Also, one of the objectives of making it dynamic is that I don't have to worry about sizes and spacing.  Could you elaborate more on what you mean though?

Comment: Please see the update to my answer . And where does that image come from because it doesn't look like anything that you've done or I've done

Comment: That's from the fiddle at the beginning of my updated post.  You can use arrow keys to rotate the object on the x and y axis.

Comment: I updated the fiddle again. Now there is a way to toggle between using the panel size and menu height to calculate the radius.

Comment: I think the magic bullet was `position: absolute` on the panels!  Literally the only thing I changed in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/scottbeeson/ue4c7ocj/8/

Comment: Follow up question if you are interested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44050486/how-can-i-center-this-dynamically-created-3d-object-on-its-parent