# How can I center this dynamically created 3d object on it's parent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[Here is the fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/scottbeeson/ue4c7ocj/8/)  Here is a screenshot:

[image]

It's obvious from the screenshot, but even more when you start applying some rotation.  Ideally I wouldn't even have to specify a height or width for the container.

How can I accomplish this?

Here is the important code:

```
function RotaMenu ( el ) {
    this.element = el;
    this.rotationX = 0;
    this.rotationY = 0;
    this.panelCount = 0;
    this.menuHeight = 0;
    this.theta = 0;
    this.radius = 0;
}

RotaMenu.prototype.update = function() {
    this.panelCount = this.element.children().length;
    this.menuHeight = $(this.element).outerHeight();
  this.panelSize = $(this.element).children().first().outerHeight();
    this.theta = 360 / this.panelCount;
  if ($('input[name=whichSize]:checked').val() == 'p') {
        this.radius = Math.round( ( this.panelSize / 2) / Math.tan( Math.PI / this.panelCount ) );
  } else {
        this.radius = Math.round( ( this.menuHeight / 2) / Math.tan( Math.PI / this.panelCount ) );
  }
    var m = this;
    $(this.element).children().each(function(i) {
        var angle = m.theta * i;
        $(this).css('transform','rotateX(' + angle + 'deg) translateZ(' + m.radius + 'px)');
    });
    $(this.element).css('transform','translateZ(' + this.radius + 'px) ' + 'rotateX(' + this.rotationX + 'deg) rotateY(' + this.rotationY + 'deg)');
    $('#labelc').text('Panels: ' + this.panelCount);
};
```

And the relevant CSS:

```
.menu-container {
    position: absolute;
    perspective: 1000px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -100px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -150px;
}
.menu {
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position: absolute;
  transition: .1s;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transform-origin: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.15);
}
.menu   div {
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Here is a previous question that may possibly provide some context: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44029222/dynamically-build-a-3d-cylinder-of-elements-with-jquery/44029938

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add these attributes to .menu  div:

top: 50%; 
left: 50%; 
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

Because of the complex position structure that you have, make sure to test compatibility issues.